# Aurelia, running webpack-dev-server --hot throws error on App Hot Update - 'Cannot read property 'status' of undefined'

Tags: webpack, webpack-hmr, aurelia, webpack-hot-middleware

I downloaded a fresh copy of the Aurelia Navigation Skeleton [github repo](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext-webpack)
. 
I execute the `npm run server:dev:hot`, which is mapped to `cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run webpack-dev-server -- --inline --progress --profile --watch --hot`.

The webpack-server starts fine, I see in the console [HMR] is waiting for WDS signal.
Everything is fine until I make a change in in a js file to trigger HMR refresh. Then I see an error/warning in the console.

[image]

I haven't modified anything in the code from the repo.

Comment: I updated nodejs and npm to latest - still no change.

Comment: This is happening to me too, in another project using aurelia-hot-module-reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that this is expected. Aurelia doesn't have HMR enabled yet.

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/629

http://blog.aurelia.io/2016/12/08/big-aurelia-release-update/

Can't wait for the update.

Comment: HMR is now working in the latest Aurelia Sekeleton - https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation